# Windows Vista/7 activation key – unique? Can change? Location?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

1. Is the Windows activation key unique? (The Windows Product ID, I was
   told, is not.)
2. Is it subject to change? And how about a clean install?
3. Am I correct that that is what is found (encrypted) as
   `DigitalProductId` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
       NT\CurrentVersion`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the Windows Product Key you enter during Installation is stored as a digital product ID in that registry location.

It can be [converted back to the product key](http://www.ed.scherer.name/Tools/MicrosoftDigitalProductIDDecoder.html)

or if Windows is still bootable use a [keyfinder program](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) to recover it.

If you use factory recovery media made for your PC you will not need a Product Key (Dell, HP, etc), it will install one automatically and pre-activate the OS. These are called Volume Licence Keys and are different than the one printed on your COA sticker, a recovered/converted VLK will not work for manual installations when you use other install media than what was supplied with the PC.